# Custom action for default push

Tags: git, gerrit

My company uses [Gerrit Code Review](http://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) for Git. I've been given a custom incantation to use every time I want to push code changes:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/my-branch-name
```

Other than "my-branch-name", that's it verbatim. The `refs/for/` syntax seems crazy to me, and is not something I'd seen before in Git.

How can I configure my repo so that `git push` alone does the same as the above?

Comment: See also the related question, ["Why do git push gerrit HEAD:refs/for/master instead of git push origin master"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10461214/405017).

Comment: Duplicate of [git alias for HEAD:refs/for/master](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423893/git-alias-for-headrefs-for-master)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the push ref-spec for your remote by typing

```
git config remote.origin.push HEAD:refs/for/my-branch-name
```

I've created a [git post-checkout hook](https://gist.github.com/4508945) that makes sure all branches (and master) are configured for use with gerrit. I think it works but your work flow might differ from mine so read the script and understand it (it's not hard) before using it.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax isn't crazy, it's just the full `git push` syntax.  When you do `git push` by itself, it really works out to be:

```
git push origin current-branch:refs/heads/current-branch
```

You're probably using gerrit for code review, so instead of just pushing directly onto a particular branch, you want to let gerrit know about the change - gerrit uses the `refs/for` area for that purpose.

Newer versions of gerrit use `refs/publish` and `refs/drafts`, so you might see those, too.

If you want something more convenient, you can easily make aliases and add them to your git configuration.  Check out this question: [git alias for HEAD:refs/for/master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423893/git-alias-for-headrefs-for-master)

Comment: _"you can easily make aliases and add them to your git configuration"_ You presume too much, sir. :p

Comment: Thank you for finding [the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423893/git-alias-for-headrefs-for-master) that has the answer I need. I'll +1 you for that, and vote to close my own question. :)

Answer (score 0):

`refs/for/....` is a "magical" ref that Gerrit uses to trigger and keep track of code reviews for a particular branch. This is documented at http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5.1/user-upload.html

You need to push to this ref so that Gerrit can pick up your changes and start the code review process.

If you just did `git push origin master` then it would bypass Gerrit since your commits would already be in the master branch. The whole point of Gerrit is make sure that your code is reviewed before it makes it into `master` (or whatever).

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the question of how to configure the repo so that `git push` does the magical incantation for me.

Comment: You can create a git alias to do that.

Comment: Given that this is the entire question, perhaps you should amend your "answer" to show how to do this. Otherwise, this is a helpful comment, but not an answer.