# how to config git to able to push refs/heads/*:refs/for/* easier

Tags: git, push, gerrit

I am looking for an easier way to push changes to Gerrit review branch. My repo contains several branches and now I need to use the full push command:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/<branch>
```

And I would like to use something easier for every branch like `git push` or `git push <remote>`. I found some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423893/git-alias-for-headrefs-for-master) for this, but it is works only with master branch.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [git-review](https://github.com/openstack-infra/git-review). You will be able to push your code with simple command

```
git review branchname
```