# How do I make reviews mandatory on gerrit?

Tags: gerrit

I would like to know if is there a way to not make optional the push request. I want all of them to go directly to review. Is is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just push your changes to refs/for/ and they go directly to review. There is no "optional" push request in Gerrit. Have a look at the [Gerrit introduction](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-quick.html) for more info.

Comment: But the user can forget to push into /refs/for. That is what I mean

Comment: You have some options to work on this. You could, for example, to create an alias (using bash or Git itself) or you could use "git config" to configure a Git remote. Take a look at some examples at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423893/git-alias-for-headrefs-for-master

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Gerrit server to reject direct pushes to branches, then refs/for and hence reviews are mandatory.